# No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'oidc' Identity Server 4.0

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using Identity Server 4.0  trying to create, Mictosoft Identity for user autenticaion and when
trying to create an mvc client I am stuck to the exception InvalidOperationException:

```
No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'oidc'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("oidc",...)?
```

Here is my AddServices in the identity Server app

```
 protected override IServiceCollection AddServices(
        IServiceCollection services)
    

{
    string inboxIdentityConnectionString = Configuration
            .GetConnectionString("InboxIdentityConnectionString");
    string identityServerConnectionString = Configuration
        .GetConnectionString("IdentityServerConnectionString");

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(
            config =>
            {
                // Sign-In
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

                // Password settings
                config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

                // Lockout settings
                config.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                config.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                config.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<InboxIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddDbContext<InboxIdentityDbContext>(
        options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(inboxIdentityConnectionString));        

    services.AddIdentityServer(
            options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
        // see the IdentityServerBuilderExtensions - this extension also adds the
        // custom user claims via the injection of the InboxInsightProfileService
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()

        .AddConfigurationStore(
            options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerConnectionString);
            })


        .AddOperationalStore(
            options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>

                builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerConnectionString);

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 60; // interval in seconds, short for testing
            })

        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();        
    return services;
}
```

And the StartUp in my Client

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddDefaultOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        string authority,
        string clientId,
        string clientSecret,
        string signoutRedirectUrl,
        string requestedScopes,
        string responseType = "code id_token",
        string loginPath = "/SignIn",
        string accessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied")
    {

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

                  services.AddAuthentication(
                options =>
                {
                    // Added as part of IdentityServer4Core2 update
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
            .AddCookie(
                "Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = loginPath;
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = accessDeniedPath;
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
                })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(
                "oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = authority;
                    options.ClientId = clientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                    options.ResponseType = responseType;

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = signoutRedirectUrl;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    var scopes = requestedScopes
                        .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => s.Trim());

                    foreach (var scope in scopes)
                    {
                        options.Scope.Add(scope);
                    }

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
                    };

                    // We need to grab and persist the ClaimsIssuer information
                    // github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1449#issuecomment-332767846
                    // https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/1124#issuecomment-280079805
                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated += ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.Options.ClaimsIssuer = ctx.SecurityToken.Issuer;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };

                    // We could either map each required claim, as described in the following
                    // link, or we can roll our own and get all available claims.
                    // https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/
                    // For example, something like this (untested):
                    // options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("org", "org");
                    options.ClaimActions.Add(new MapAllClaimAction());
                });

        return services;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following in your MVC client startup class?

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```